# How do I call a function when bootstrap collapse expands

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I want to activate this javascript:

```
jsPlumb.repaintEverything();
```

...and fire up an alert box saying "I'm expanding!!!" when a user clicks the button in [**this fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/jnoweb/oob4pjy5/)

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `shown.bs.collapse` event that Bootstrap raises:

```
$('#demo').on('shown.bs.collapse', function() {
    jsPlumb.repaintEverything();
});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/oob4pjy5/1/)

Note that this event fires *after* the element expansion animation has completed. If you want to run the code as the animation starts, use `show.bs.collapse` instead

Answer (score 0):

You have [two events in Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-events) that supports your requirement.

**show.bs.collapse** -  This event fires immediately when the show instance method is called.
**shown.bs.collapse** - This event is fired when a collapse element has been made visible to the user (will wait for CSS transitions to complete).

> fire up an alert box saying "I'm expanding!!!"

So what you need is `show.bs.collapse` which is triggered just before the the `div` is shown

```
$('#demo').on('show.bs.collapse', function() {
    jsPlumb.repaintEverything();
});
```