# Using Angular 7, how do I call a function when Bootstrap Collapse expands?

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

I am building a Hacker news clone using Angular 7 and what I am trying to achieve is when the user clicks on a button next to a comment they will see the child comments.

I have added Bootstrap 4 [Collapse](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/) and what I would like to do is to call a function passing the required comment ids when Collapse is expanded so once the panel has expanded it shows the child comments.

I am aware that Collapse has several events that I can use and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40931493/how-do-i-call-a-function-when-bootstrap-collapse-expands) shows an example but I don't know to add that to my component.

Here is what I have attempted so far and the function I want to call is getCommentDetails and pass it the child comments ids.

**comments.component.html**

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<div class="container">  
  <div class="row" *ngFor="let comment of commentDetails let i = index">
    <!-- only display the expand button if there are child comments -->
    <p *ngIf="comment.kids?.length > 0">
      <a class="btn btn-primary" 
         data-toggle="collapse" 
         href="#collapseExample_{{i}}" 
         role="button" 
         aria-expanded="false" 
         aria-controls="collapseExample"
         (click)="getCommentDetails(comment.kids)">
      </a>
    </p>    
    <p [innerHTML]="comment.text"></p>
    <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample_{{i}}">
      <div class="card card-body">
        <p [innerHTML]="comment.text"></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**comments.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CommentsTransferService } from '../services/comments-transfer.service';
import { HackerNewsService } from '../services/hackernews.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-comments',
  templateUrl: './comments.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./comments.component.css']
})
export class CommentsComponent implements OnInit {

  commentIDs: number[];
  commentDetails: any[];

  constructor(private commentsTransferService: CommentsTransferService,
              private hackerNewsService: HackerNewsService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getCommentDetails(this.commentsTransferService.getCommentIDs());
    this.hackerNewsService.getCommentTree(this.commentsTransferService.getCommentIDs()).subscribe(
      data => {
        console.log('comment tree is ', data );
        Object.assign(this, data);            
      },
      error => console.log(error)
    );

  }

  getCommentDetails(commentIds: number[]) {
    this.commentDetails = this.hackerNewsService.getComments(commentIds);
    console.log(this.commentDetails);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Angular with Bootstrap you should probably switch to NgBootstrap. Its all the goodness of Bootstrap but works directly with angular.

Here is the documentation for what you are using:
https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/collapse/examples

This is the basics of how it would look.

```
<div class="container">  
  <div class="row" *ngFor="let comment of commentDetails let i = index">
    <!-- only display the expand button if there are child comments -->
    <p *ngIf="comment.kids?.length > 0">
      <a class="btn btn-primary" 
         [attr.aria-expanded]="!isCollapsed" 
         aria-controls="collapseExample"
         (click)="getCommentDetails(comment.kids); isCollapsed = !isCollapsed">
      </a>
    </p>    
    <p>{{comment.text}}</p>
    <div id="collapseExample_{{i}}" [ngbCollapse]="isCollapsed">
      <div class="card card-body">
        <p>{{comment.text}}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```